# Is it possible to make seams thicker in Bender?

Tags: uv, interface, customization, edges

Is it possible to make uv seams thicker in the 3d view in Blender?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At the minute, no, that does not appear to be an option. You can view all available theme options for the 3D view by going to *File> User Preferences> Themes> 3D View*:

[image]

Comment: Yeah i have looked inside here before. Its wierd because you can change the width on "highlight selected" so i was hoping perhaps i had missed some settings somewhere. anyway thanks!

Comment: If this has answered your question, feel free to mark this question as 'accepted' by clicking the tick icon next to the answer. See:http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers